# System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage not working for out of range window

Tags: c#

I currently encounter strange result when I try to get a screenshot from a window which I set outside of "the standard desktop range".

I want to simulate a background process screenshot without being backgrounded.
For this I use the MoveWindow trick as follow :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SetActiveWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref RECT rectangle);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{

    private int _Left;
    private int _Top;
    private int _Right;
    private int _Bottom;

    public RECT(RECT rectangle)
        : this(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom)
    {

    }

    public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        _Left = left;
        _Top = top;
        _Right = right;
        _Bottom = bottom;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }

    public int Left
    {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }

    public int Top
    {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }

    public int Right
    {
        get { return _Right; }
        set { _Right = value; }
    }

    public int Bottom
    {
        get { return _Bottom; }
        set { _Bottom = value; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
        set { _Bottom = value + _Top; }
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get { return _Right - _Left; }
        set { _Right = value + _Left; }
    }

    public Point Location
    {
        get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
        set
        {
            _Left = value.X;
            _Top = value.Y;
        }
    }

    public Size Size
    {
        get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
        set
        {
            _Right = value.Width + _Left;
            _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT rectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
    }

    public static implicit operator RECT(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        return new RECT(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(RECT rectangle1, RECT rectangle2)
    {
        return rectangle1.Equals(rectangle2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(RECT rectangle1, RECT rectangle2)
    {
        return !rectangle1.Equals(rectangle2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT rectangle)
    {
        return rectangle.Left == _Left && rectangle.Top == _Top && rectangle.Right == _Right && rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object Object)
    {
        if (Object is RECT)
        {
            return Equals((RECT)Object);
        }
        else if (Object is Rectangle)
        {
            return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
        }

        return false;
    }

}

private static void hideTarget(IntPtr targetWindow)
{
    GetWindowRect(targetWindow, ref _lastWindowPosition);
    MoveWindow(targetWindow, -10000, -10000, _lastWindowPosition.Width, _lastWindowPosition.Height, true);
}
```

With this, the target window disappear from the desktop range and can be considered as "backgrounded".

To get screenshot I use the following code :

```
private static Bitmap getForcedScreenShot(IntPtr hWnd, bool screen) {
    RECT rect = new RECT();
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rect);

    Bitmap bmpScreenshot = Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
    var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    SetActiveWindow(hWnd);

    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(rect.X, rect.Y, 0, 0, rect.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    SetActiveWindow(hWnd);

    if (screen)
        bmpScreenshot.Save("ScreenshotForced" + DateTime.Now.ToString("_dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss_fff") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);

    return bmpScreenshot;
}
```

When calling method, saved screen is empty. Everything works as intended if application isn't "backgrounded".

**Questions:**

Is there a way to work with this code without being in the active range ?
If not, is there any other way to get regional screenshot ?

**PS** : I tried with "PrintWindow" from pinvoke but it's not working too.

Thanks !

Comment: I assume that "doesnt work" means the resulting image is blank or empty?  That is because Windows is optimized: it doesnt draw things the user cannot see like windows behind other windows or windows offscreen

Comment: Yes the screen is empty. Is there a way to force windows to draw specific region for a short time lapse ?